# Why does a hexagonal chess board skip the letter J?

Tags: chess-variants, hexagonal-chess

For every Glinski's Hexagonal Chess game I see online the algebraic notation skips J for I K L. Why? What's wrong with J?
[image]

Comment: I would err a lot on the side of avoiding confusion between i and j, which in some fonts can look identical, and since there's L too